# How to use Asynchronous Module Definitions(AMD) in SS2.1?

Tags: excel, netsuite, suitescript, amd, sheetjs

I'm trying to import SheetJS Library to SuiteScript and read "xlsx" file data. I follow the SheetJS tutorial step, like this:https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/demos/cloud/netsuite/

After upload file to the SuiteScript Folder, run the Suitelet still show error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'read' of undefined".

That error in SheetJS means "The root cause is an undefined `XLSX` variable. This usually means the library was not properly loaded." But I already imported the "xlsx.full.min.js" file into NetSuite SuiteScript folder. How can I resolve that problem?

Here is my Code:
JsLibraryConfig.json

```
{
    "paths": {
        "xlsx": "/SuiteScripts/xlsx.full.min.js"
    }
}
```

Suitelet

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 * @NModuleScope Public
 * @NAmdConfig  /SuiteScripts/JsLibraryConfig.json
 * @module jszip
 * @module xlsx
 */


define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/search', 'N/redirect', 'N/format', 'N/runtime', 'N/record', 'N/url', 'N/currentRecord',  'N/file', 'jszip','xlsx'],
    function (serverWidget, search, redirect, format, runtime, record, url, currentRecord, file, JSZIP, XLSX) {
function onRequest(context) {
...
 var fileObj = file.load({ id: fileId });
                    var b64 = fileObj.getContents();
                    log.debug('b64', b64)
                    var workbook = XLSX.read(b64, { type: "base64" });
}
...
return {
            onRequest: onRequest,
        };
  });
```

My File Place
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFnVA.png)

Another question, I want to know the "xlsx.full.min.js" have many garbled texts is normal?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHJmS.png)

Thanks in advance.

I have been found SuiteAnswer, reddit and stackoverflow, but I still can't resolve my problem.
Hope someone can help, Thanks

Comment: Try with omitting the .js extension: `"xlsx": "/SuiteScripts/xlsx.full.min"`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I resolve it, but it seems like not the .js extension's problem. I just tried again today, and it worked. It' s so weird !